# Reference a relation in create Odata via REST

Tags: entity-framework, rest, odata

So, I'm trying to create a record in someone else's Entity Framework application using REST.

When performing a **POST** request with the following payload:

```
POST /Invoice
{
  "Tenant_Id": "a",
  "InvoiceNumber": "d",
  "Invoice_DateTime": "5/19/2015 6:2:26 AM",
  "InvoicePrint": "false",
  "Invoice_Updated": "5/19/2015 6:2:26 AM",
  "External_Id": ""
}
```

I get the error:

> "Entities in 'DataEntities.Invoices' participate in the
>   'FK_tblInvoice_tblJob' relationship. 0 related 'tblJob' were found. 1
>   'tblJob' is expected."

I have attempted to create the reference to job by appending the following to the **POST** payload:

```
"Job": {
    "__metadata": {
      "uri": "https://.../Job(4095603)"
    }
```

But that just gives me this error instead:

> "Resource not found for the segment 'Job'."

---

For reference, this is what the **GET** result looks like:

```
GET /Invoices?$top=1
{
  "d": [
    {
      "__metadata": {
        "id": "https://.../Invoices(421847)",
        "uri": "https://.../Invoices(421847)",
        "type": "DataModel.Invoices"
      },
      "Job": {
        "__deferred": {
          "uri": "https://.../Invoices(421847)/Job"
        }
      },
      "Tenant_Id": "a",
      "Invoice_Id": 421847,
      "InvoiceNumber": "b",
      "Invoice_DateTime": "/Date(1396924200000)/",
      "InvoiceDescription": null,
      "InvoicePrint": false,
      "Invoice_Updated": null,
      "External_Id": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**So how do I reference the Job that has already been created in the new Invoice request?**

Comment: Which version of odata are you using? Have a look at the ``$ref` (for v4) or `$link` (for v3). http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#relationship

Comment: v2... I think (how do you check?)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a child object you only need to reference the {parent object}/{object}

Example:

```
POST /Jobs(4095603)/Invoices
{
  "Tenant_Id": "a",
  "InvoiceNumber": "d",
  "Invoice_DateTime": "5/19/2015 6:2:26 AM",
  "InvoicePrint": "false",
  "Invoice_Updated": "5/19/2015 6:2:26 AM",
  "External_Id": ""
}
```